# Performance hit for enabling metrics in Wildfly 10.1

Tags: java, performance, jakarta-ee, wildfly, monitoring

In the WildFly management console, I can enable statistics and metrics for various subsystems like data sources and persistence units. Is there / what is the performance hit in doing so? Is this a problem on a production system?

Answer (score 0):

There is negligible hit in performance if you access statistics of resources frequently. To avoid performance impact only, they are disabled by default.

Comment: Thanks. So just collecting the statistics is not an issue as long as I do not check them too frequently?